# NSNotification before 2 days from targeted date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to fire a notification before 2 days from targeted date.Currently I am using below code to fire notification but there how to fire notification exactly before 2 days from targeted date.

```
    NSString *frstdate = [[calenderarray objectAtIndex:k] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"frstdate..%@",frstdate);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:frstdate]; 
    NSLog(@"date..%@",date);
    NSDate *dateToFire = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-24*60*60 sinceDate:date]autorelease];
     NSLog(@"dateToFire..%@",dateToFire);
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
         return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
     localNotif.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Get Food"], @"foodItem", nil] ;
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

    Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What is `itemDate`? Did you mean to write `dateToFire` there?

Comment: Are you using native Calendar app to add these events

Comment: yes i use native calender app for add events.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to do the maths - something like:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* twoDaysAgo = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
twoDaysAgo.day = -2;
NSDate* dateToFire = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:twoDaysAgo toDate:date options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do arithmetic with calendar dates (year/month/day/hour... representation in a given timezone) via the NSCalendar class. Although in most cases, "24*60*60" seconds will be one day -- users probably won't notice the difference.